# While reading the excel in VB.net if we have the columns more than Z like AA,AB,AC getting the error HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am reading an excel which has the columns more than Z like AA,AB,AC,for that i am getting the error
HRESULT: 0x800A03EC.If i have only till Z its working fine.
I am getting the value "[1" instead of AA1.Could you please help.

```
   For i = 1 To 1
        For j = 0 To mColumn - 1 Step 1
            ExcelRange = wsExcel.Range((CChar(ChrW(65 + j)) & i))
            For k = 0 To NomColonne.Count - 1
                If ExcelRange.Value <> Nothing Then
                    If ExcelRange.Value.ToString = NomColonne(k) Then
                        NoLigne(k) = i
                        NoColonne(k) = j
                    End If
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
```

Comment: `CChar(ChrW(65 + j))` won't work past Z, you need to write a new function that will return AA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following instead:

```
ExcelRange = wsExcel.Range(ExcelColumnLabel(j) & i))
```

where

```
''' <summary>
''' Returns the equivalent Excel column name (e.g. A, B, AA, AB, etc.)
''' </summary>
''' <param name="i">Required Integer. 0-based column number</param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Function ExcelColumnLabel(i As Integer) As String
  Dim strOutput As String = ""
  strOutput = Chr(65 + (i Mod 26))
  If i > 25 Then
    strOutput = Chr(64 + (i \ 26) Mod 26) & strOutput
    If i > 26 * 26 - 1 Then
      strOutput = Chr(64 + ((i \ 26) \ 26) Mod 26) & strOutput
    End If
  End If
  Return strOutput
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much ,i have changed the function.Now its working fine.

Comment: It is silly to go to great lengths to convert the column number into the letter, when you can [use the column number directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76314537/11683) to refer to the range.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell what kind of object `wsExcel` or `ExcelRange` is, but I assume `wsExcel` is a worksheet and `ExcelRange` is a range. But if you just want the address you can use:

```
Cells(i, j)
```

The address as a string would be:

```
Cells(i, j).Address
```

and without dollar signs would be:

```
Replace(Cells(i, j).Address, "$", "")
```

`Step 1` is the default, so you don't need it. I also don't see why you need a `For` from 1 to 1.